# UPD: Как настроить отображение картинок в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, изображения, img, create-react-app

Вопрос избитый, неоднократно обсуждаем, с кучей решений и тд.. Но!

Проблема. Не отображаются картинки в проекте.
Реакт, компонент jsx.

**путь компонента:**
/src/components/post/post.jsx

**Пробовал закинуть изображение в:**
-папку public
-в public/images

-в папку src
-в src/images
-в /src/components/images

**Картинка отображается в двух случаях:**

1. если она лежит в папке с компонентом. Рядом.
2. или если тупо импортировать, и вставлять
   import mops from './images/mops.jpeg';
   src={mops} (но такой вариант не подходит, тк в дальнейшем картинок будет много, и возможно будут динамически меняться)

Не понимаю, в чем проблема, тк в других проектах такого не было.
Перепробовал кучу всего, и ничего не помогло.

Заранее спасибо

upd: при инспектировании страницы, увидел ошибку в консоли:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  ------  1.jpeg:1

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас такой вид проекта:

- src/

  - components/

    - post/

      - post.jsx
    - images/

Если да, то вам нужно импортировать не из ./images, a ../images

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет:

```html
<img src={require('./images/mops.jpeg').default} alt='mops'/>
```